# java decryption rsa from javascript encrypt

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptography

I Passwork by RSA encryption using javascript string 
I use the following pages to create privatekey and publickey 
http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/ 
public key and private key 
I want to decode using java 
I have tried many many times but have problems
Please help me.
thanks

```
String sprivatekey = "MIICWwIBAAKBgHWiNo/ql4zfT/DA3tr+atZZef01wrwSiPaD3M3efki7/o1NZxvP"
        + "PyjcIrGT/qMrVGE9ncj4+y+vb8C1K2gyegKJwS8vF74Dvlzt2VL/3BZpfmZ1WACt"
        + "5xNzme10lxyH2LERXOrUzr5YHsgraa+wabS90amja02/BrkY9NYi7QqXAgMBAAEC"
        + "gYBAKUQdZ1VWDw+pP2nOhOp9E7zH8aTPtERkQTQUTgEPZwrGw6szrezDOp7pwNEo"
        + "6p9RkqwXTEalkckgkTCl2rJVIcjjGsselQf0RXYAKeLUkojhl+ypVrFbMN6/IYd/"
        + "/FkV57eSY2eYZ2+wRAz18zrEtSS/wWaiRMwV6Tb9ON72IQJBANoqDT0S9R2FoQ0F"
        + "uDvXB6IlGh0/QbewYDs5/An/rLi1ZexAtBTqn9DJ9MjR7Jp2OpYaGWBgE/0J+8Dy"
        + "n+Bow7kCQQCKCNpjeMd3RQc8uQmdSFEK8b1vWxi+phB95oKfsqA1Zf7IJDvxInhJ"
        + "BkAWHK6dzWCwYR23sJrF/shkXPm3YQjPAkBVxmjUFWsIA20RuKj55g5bQukkjKVi"
        + "+larkp20tLCNIs0C+WGUQ7c4GN9EQb0b8dYRBAvsJ3pUZ6Ny9jHDwo0JAkATV2A6"
        + "de8FIE/+SzM0rbBlZzATDWGvPResfIMrG11lfhAwPRuFEz5lhRGvx38UL3Xv4PvI"
        + "BF/7hFLR9VEsR9VzAkEAzAX2TggCaPaYFpLWIZH2NSKjuOrKXLI3zEwIaVjM55dd"
        + "Kcj97JyOzC5vurPpw6TZOWiGJ3bZRswJXcCxWianMw==";

String spublickey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCS6nsbqyNtrv7dMm9mje98L8So"
        + "W/wgL9CzahjSHq56YcV4qyapuT9HOglCbD12xyM9bi0bvg5wkyJ37oMWNvxsiYh9"
        + "u0eLZlzOIR+2CmjeL2OZDqGqn7HFCdfbbX9mdTkm4mE+pVOsWIuts2ZegMeU9EWz"
        + "M91ZGA0mBug6VaavswIDAQAB";
String plainText="Tacdsfddfdfd"; 
String cipherText="YlXqYjr+rNUnh9Cta6wMWamqNsVGuRc01NA3qjtazdtcKJoJ5yfPQmq9OJo3Qc9k2JztzmFvSDyV83Bru8fl/xcflFjb/H+IL966lXGVh83QTQaVGTwMkV37iYvz+oCJmOmq6f+O34/0u0qilvgNgfAevYZY2ZWTbaGYvS1pXmQ=";
```

I use java string key read into PrivateKey 
Method read privatekey

```
 public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromString(String key)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
RSAPrivateKey pk;
byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.decodeBase64(key);
try {
    public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA"; 
    ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence
            .fromByteArray(encodedPrivateKey);
    Enumeration<?> e = primitive.getObjects();
    BigInteger v = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();

    int version = v.intValue();
    if (version != 0 && version != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "wrong version for RSA private key");
    }
    BigInteger modulus = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger privateExponent = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement())
            .getValue();
    RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus,
            privateExponent);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    pk = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(spec);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
return pk;
```

}

Method decrypt java

```
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
public static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherText;
}
public static String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) {
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
        // SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // random.nextBytes(text);
        // decrypt the text using the private key
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(dectyptedText);
}
```

call decrypt

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sprivatekey = "MIICWwIBAAKBgHWiNo/ql4zfT/DA3tr+atZZef01wrwSiPaD3M3efki7/o1NZxvP"
            + "PyjcIrGT/qMrVGE9ncj4+y+vb8C1K2gyegKJwS8vF74Dvlzt2VL/3BZpfmZ1WACt"
            + "5xNzme10lxyH2LERXOrUzr5YHsgraa+wabS90amja02/BrkY9NYi7QqXAgMBAAEC"
            + "gYBAKUQdZ1VWDw+pP2nOhOp9E7zH8aTPtERkQTQUTgEPZwrGw6szrezDOp7pwNEo"
            + "6p9RkqwXTEalkckgkTCl2rJVIcjjGsselQf0RXYAKeLUkojhl+ypVrFbMN6/IYd/"
            + "/FkV57eSY2eYZ2+wRAz18zrEtSS/wWaiRMwV6Tb9ON72IQJBANoqDT0S9R2FoQ0F"
            + "uDvXB6IlGh0/QbewYDs5/An/rLi1ZexAtBTqn9DJ9MjR7Jp2OpYaGWBgE/0J+8Dy"
            + "n+Bow7kCQQCKCNpjeMd3RQc8uQmdSFEK8b1vWxi+phB95oKfsqA1Zf7IJDvxInhJ"
            + "BkAWHK6dzWCwYR23sJrF/shkXPm3YQjPAkBVxmjUFWsIA20RuKj55g5bQukkjKVi"
            + "+larkp20tLCNIs0C+WGUQ7c4GN9EQb0b8dYRBAvsJ3pUZ6Ny9jHDwo0JAkATV2A6"
            + "de8FIE/+SzM0rbBlZzATDWGvPResfIMrG11lfhAwPRuFEz5lhRGvx38UL3Xv4PvI"
            + "BF/7hFLR9VEsR9VzAkEAzAX2TggCaPaYFpLWIZH2NSKjuOrKXLI3zEwIaVjM55dd"
            + "Kcj97JyOzC5vurPpw6TZOWiGJ3bZRswJXcCxWianMw==";

    String spublickey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCS6nsbqyNtrv7dMm9mje98L8So"
            + "W/wgL9CzahjSHq56YcV4qyapuT9HOglCbD12xyM9bi0bvg5wkyJ37oMWNvxsiYh9"
            + "u0eLZlzOIR+2CmjeL2OZDqGqn7HFCdfbbX9mdTkm4mE+pVOsWIuts2ZegMeU9EWz"
            + "M91ZGA0mBug6VaavswIDAQAB";

    try {
        PrivateKey privateKey = RSAKey.getPrivateKeyFromString(sprivatekey);
        //PublicKey publicKey = RSAKey.getPublicKeyFromString(spublickey);
        String v = "YlXqYjr+rNUnh9Cta6wMWamqNsVGuRc01NA3qjtazdtcKJoJ5yfPQmq9OJo3Qc9k2JztzmFvSDyV83Bru8fl/xcflFjb/H+IL966lXGVh83QTQaVGTwMkV37iYvz+oCJmOmq6f+O34/0u0qilvgNgfAevYZY2ZWTbaGYvS1pXmQ=";
        //Call method 1
        String plainText1 = decrypt(v.getBytes(), privateKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + plainText1);
        //Call method 2
        String plainText2 = decrypt(v, privateKey); 
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + plainText2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error call Method 1

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:346)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
at com.evnit.futil.security.EncryptionUtil.decrypt(EncryptionUtil.java:146)
at com.evnit.futil.security.EncryptionUtil.main(EncryptionUtil.java:201)
```

Error call Method 2

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:365)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
at com.evnit.futil.security.EncryptionUtil.decrypt(EncryptionUtil.java:167)
at com.evnit.futil.security.EncryptionUtil.main(EncryptionUtil.java:204)
```

Comment: `I have tried many many times but have problems` - perhaps if you shared what your problems are, someone may be able to help you ... as it stands, this is barely a question, let alone a good question

Comment: @Flanker The ciphertext that you have looks like it's Base64-encoded, but JCE only operates on the actual bytes. You need to decode the ciphertext first.

Comment: You shouldn't try decoding & decrypting stuff created by complete nitwits. The modulus of the key pair is 1023 bits in size.

Comment: Ah, that's not a problem of the page but of the private key you put in. Why didn't you tell us that you tried a key not generated by that page, you ****. Where can I send the bill?